# Generic class fails to accept object with direct line to the generic where type restriction

Tags: c#, generics

I have a c# data class defined with an inheritance chain that looks like this:

```
public abstract class EntityBaseCore
public abstract class EntityBase : EntityBaseCore
public partial class AdmSite : EntityBase
```

And a generic class defined like this:

```
public abstract class ViewModelSecurityBase<T> : Screen, where T : EntityBaseCore
public abstract class EditorViewModelBase<T> : ViewModelSecurityBase<T> where T : EntityBaseCore
```

My view model class looks like this:

```
public class SiteViewModel : EditorViewModelBase<AdmSite>
```

This fails with

```
The type 'Yargo.DataModel.AdmSite' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Yargo.Common.ViewModel.EditorViewModelBase'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Yargo.DataModel.AdmSite' to 'Yargo.DataModel.EntityBaseCore'
```

The inheritance chain between AdmSite and EntityBaseCode seems direct. I don't understand why this is failing.

Comment: Do you have 2 classes called AdmSite in different namespace?

Comment: I did a search on the name in Object Browser and it only finds the one class (cross complied into desktop and Silverlight assemblies).  The code in question is on the Silverlight end of things.

Comment: What if you don't inherit `ViewModelSecurityBase<T>` ? Does it work ?

Comment: Seb, Unfortunately both generic base classes are pretty involved and taking one out of the chain breaks a lot of things.  This solution was a working database-first Entity Framework project being converted to code-first.  Darkmyst below gives me confidence it _should_ work, but something environmental is causing things not to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to work for me.

```
public class Screen { }
public abstract class EntityBaseCore
{    }

public abstract class EntityBase : EntityBaseCore
{    }
public partial class AdmSite : EntityBase
{    }

public abstract class ViewModelSecurityBase<T> : Screen where T : EntityBaseCore
{    }
public abstract class EditorViewModelBase<T> : ViewModelSecurityBase<T> where T : EntityBaseCore
{    }

public class SiteViewModel : EditorViewModelBase<AdmSite>
{    }
```

Comment: Well, EntityBaseCore, EntityBase, and SiteViewModel are all in different assemblies, but the references seem correct to me. Intellisense seems to pick them up correctly but the compiler seems to be getting lost.

Comment: I factored EntityBaseCore into an interface and restricted the generics to that.  All the pieces seem to be coming together now.  Thanks for your help.  Stupid of me not to have tried exactly what you did.